# ServiceStack ORMLite: Best way to alias primary table and select list in query with join?

Tags: c#, sql, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I have the following ORMLite query in which I wish to return the columns from the primary table, i.e. the one referenced by the `From<T>()` method, filtered by a join to a secondary table.

```
var query = conn
    .From<SurveyQuestionOptionDTO>()
    .Join<SurveyQuestionDTO>((o, q) => o.SurveyQuestionId == q.Id, conn.JoinAlias("q"))
    .Where<SurveyQuestionDTO>(q => q.SurveyId == surveyId);

return conn.Select(query);
```

This generates the following SQL query

```
SELECT "Id", "SurveyQuestionId", "Option", "Selected", "Sequence" 
  FROM "dbo"."SurveyQuestionOptions"
  INNER JOIN "dbo"."SurveyQuestions" q
    ON ("dbo"."SurveyQuestionOptions"."SurveyQuestionId" = "q"."Id")
  WHERE ("dbo"."SurveyQuestions"."SurveyId" = @0)
```

This would be fine except that both tables have `Id` and `Sequence` columns so the query fails with ambiguous column references. If I was hand-coding the SQL I would simply alias the `SurveyQuestionOptions` table, for instance with `o` and use that alias on each column in the select list, like `o.Id, o.SurveyQuestionId, o.Option, o.Selected, o.Sequence` or even just `o.*` as all columns are being returned. My question is, what is the best way to make ORMLite generate such code?

I have found a way to do it, by adding a `Select<T>()` method returning an anonymous class, as follows

```
var query = conn
    .From<SurveyQuestionOptionDTO>()
    .Join<SurveyQuestionDTO>(
        (o, q) => o.SurveyQuestionId == q.Id && q.SurveyId == surveyId,
        conn.JoinAlias("q"))
    .Select<SurveyQuestionOptionDTO>(o => new
    {
        o.Id,
        o.SurveyQuestionId,
        o.Option,
        o.Selected,
        o.Sequence
    });

return conn.Select(query);
```

This works, but it seems like a lot of extra code to achieve a simple result, and because columns are explicitly returned, requires this code to change if the table ever gets a new column and the DTO class is re-generated. Is there a better, simpler way?

Comment: FYI you can also add a [Table Alias](https://docs.servicestack.net/ormlite/reference-support.html#table-aliases) to the primary table with `db.From<Table>(db.TableAlias("t1"))`

Comment: That would probably do the trick. Sadly we aren't using the latest version of ORMLite so that isn't available.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a simpler way that also resolves future impact of column changes. Instead of returning a new anonymous class from the `Select<T>()` method you can simply return the instance that's passed in. So the code now looks like this, and still works as expected.

```
var query = conn
    .From<SurveyQuestionOptionDTO>()
    .Join<SurveyQuestionDTO>(
        (o, q) => o.SurveyQuestionId == q.Id && q.SurveyId == surveyId,
        conn.JoinAlias("q"))
    .Select<SurveyQuestionOptionDTO>(o => o);

return conn.Select(query);
```

Comment: ".Select<SurveyQuestionOptionDTO>(o => o)" is not needed since expression is of SurveyQuestionOptionDTO type.

Comment: @labilbe it is required because without it the generated SQL fails due to ambiguous column names. That's the whole point of this question. I had also thought that the query with just the From and Join should work, but it didn't.

Comment: You can use query.PrefixFieldWithTableName = true; or .IncludeTablePrefix() after .Join() method

Comment: query.PrefixFieldWithTableName = true is supported in OrmLite 5.0.0.0 but doesn't solve the problem. .IncludeTablePrefix() isn't supported. Before you ask; why we use such an old version is above my pay grade, as they say.